# Any reason to prefer DEVICE_LOCAL over DEVICE_LOCAL|HOST_VISIBLE memory?

Tags: vulkan

I'm using an AMD Radeon RX 7800 XT. It reports a 16GB heap that is device local.

https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=27423#memory

Heap 1 has a memory type that is DEVICE_LOCAL and a few memory types that are DEVICE_LOCAL as well as HOST_VISIBLE. I created a buffer with usage:

```
VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT |
VK_BUFFER_USAGE_INDEX_BUFFER_BIT | 
VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT
```

and I can use Memory type 0 (if I specify VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT) or Memory type 3 if I specify local as well as host visible. Both are on the same 16GB heap.

My question is if there's any reason to ever not use memory type 3? Is there any upside to using the memory type that does not have CPU access and would require staging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, you should not ask for capabilities that you're not going to use. That is, ask for the minimum capabilities that you need.

At the same time, your application should adapt to what is offered. If the GPU always offers CPU access to its device local heap (and doesn't have any device local heaps that aren't also host visible), then you can use those capabilities where you see a use for them. Images will always need staging in order to be used in tiled layouts, so mapping their memory is not the most useful thing to do. But if you want to map memory for your buffers, you can do that.

That is, it's reasonable to use memory types 0 or 1 for your images and memory types 2 or 3 for your buffers.

Comment: Does https://docs.vulkan.org/guide/latest/memory_allocation.html not suggest placing vertex, index and uniform in one buffer being optimal?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you were referring to the buffer's usage types specifically when you said not to ask for capabilities that you're not going to use. But you probably meant CPU access.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that if you're using higher type indices then there may be a performance penalty.  The assumption is that you'll want to use the lowest possible type index for whatever heap is appropriate. I would *assume* that memory allocated that has the `HOST_VISIBLE` might not perform as well as that without it.

Also bear in mind that some nVidia cards specifically [expose](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=26896#memory) specialty heaps that provide both `DEVICE_LOCAL` and `HOST_VISIBLE` but which are much smaller than the other heaps.  You can see that while there's ~8GB of device local memory and 32GB of host memory, there's 214 MEGAbytes of memory that has both `DEVICE_LOCAL` and `HOST_VISIBLE`.  That's room for a lot of uniform buffers, but I wouldn't start using it to store vertices and index data in.

All that said, manual memory management is a pain point in Vulkan, and I highly recommend using something like the [VMA](https://gpuopen.com/vulkan-memory-allocator/) library to wrap it.

Comment: "*Also bear in mind that some nVidia cards*" It's not just NVIDIA cards. [Many AMD cards do the same](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=27411#memory). Indeed, they were *first*.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks for the tip.  I don't spend a lot of time working with AMD systems, and I didn't want to make any assumptions about how broad support was for that given the only card being referenced in the question didn't have that.